Ethics Complaint Statute of Limitations [OH]
What is the statute of limitations to file an ethics complaint with the state bar association for Ohio?

According to this source:

In the context of filing a State Bar grievance, the statute of
limitations is 4 years from the date of the alleged professional
misconduct.

This is the same as the statute of limitations for legal malpractice lawsuits in Ohio which was adopted in 2021.
Both deadlines are "statutes of repose" which means that they are not dependent upon when the misconduct or malpractice is actually discovered.

A pedantic nitpick - technically a "statute of limitations" is the law which sets out time limit, while the time limit itself is a "limitation period". However this misuse of the terminology seems to be so common I guess they could be considered almost interchangeable.

@JBentley I would be of the opinion that this distinction, if it once existed, has faded out of consistent usage by lawyers and judges and that there both meanings are sense of the term "statute of limitations" these days (at least in American legal English).
